# Adding exceptionHandlers to Winston container

Tags: javascript, winston

How would I add exceptionHandlers when using Winston containers? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. I'd like to write exceptions to a specific file. Than you.

```
const container = new winston.Container()

container.add('info', {
    console: {
        level: `info`,
        silent: true,
        colorize: true,
        label: `General Logging`
    },
    file: {
        level: `info`,
        silent: false,
        filename: `path/info.log`,
        label: `General Logging`
    }
})
```